# Thread and block structure in CUDA and how to allocate threads with different structures (c++)

Tags: c++, cuda, nvidia

I have just started learning cuda and parallel programming and am having a difficult time with it. If I am declaring the size and structure of a thread block like this:

```
addKernel << < 1, 5 >> > (dev_c, dev_a, dev_b);
```

Can someone explain how I would declare the following:

```
1)One 2D block
2)One 3D block
3)multiple 2D block in 1D block grid
4)multiple 2D block in 2D block grid
5)multiple 2D block in 3D block grid
6)multiple 3D block in 1D block grid
```

and how would I do this for adding 2 larger array sizes of size 2^23-1. I don't understand what is meant by the terms above and how to represent them in the CUDA addKernel line above.

```
const int arraySize = 2^23-1;
int a[arraySize] = { 0 };
int b[arraySize] = { 0 };
int c[arraySize] = { 0 };
```

Above I have defined the array size and initialized a, b, and c. I'm trying to write code that adds the contents of a and b in parallel and stores the results in c. How would I shape the thread structure in the ways above and split the task between threads? Thank you. I'm trying to understand thread hierarchy further by implementing different way of organizing the threads and blocks.

Comment: Suggest you reduce the scope of your question, it seems like you're essentially asking for a tutorial on CUDA with a follow-up on a specific example.

Answer (score 2):

The left of the execution configuration (`<<< ... >>>`) gives you the grid dimension (ie. number of blocks in the grid), the right the block dimension (ie. number of threads in the block). Note that there are potentially up to four arguments in the runtime API kernel launch syntax, but the final two are irrelevant to this discussion.

So some examples:

1. a single 2D block with 2 threads in x- and y-direction, respectively: `<<< 1, dim3(2, 2) >>>` (note that the default values of `dim3` are 1)
2. a single 3D block: `<<< 1, dim3(2, 2, 2) >>>`
3. multiple 2D blocks in 1D grid: `<<< 4, dim3(2, 2) >>>` ("four 2D blocks")
4. multiple 2D blocks in 2D grid: `<<< dim3(3, 3), dim3(2, 2) >>>` ("three 2D blocks in x-direction, and three in y-direction")
5. multiple 2D blocks in 3D grid: `<<< dim3(3, 4, 5), dim3(2, 2) >>>` ("three 2D blocks in x-dir, four in y-dir, five in z-dir")
6. multiple 3D blocks in 1D grid: `<<< 5, dim3(2, 2, 2) >>>` ("five 3D blocks")

---

As for your latter question (sorry, this got a bit long):

In general a single dimension is all you need. 2D and 3D are just conveniences for certain problems (eg. 2D for convolution). So how you choose your dimensions is problem-dependent.

Also keep in mind that number of thread per block is quite limited (usually 1024 for x and y dimension... not sure about z right now, but the point is you can't have that many per block).

For your addition you end up doing something like this: you decide how many threads you want per block, say `numThreads` (I think a multiple of 32 is recommended, eg. 32 or 256) and you calculate the number of blocks as `ceil(n / numThreads)` where `n` is the size of your array. This ensures that you'll have at least as many threads as there are elements in your array.

Eg. if your array has `n = 1000` elements and you decide to go for `numThreadsPerBlock = 32`, you get `ceil(1000 / 32) = ceil(31.25) = 32` blocks. This means your kernel will be launched with `numBlocks * numThreadsPerBlock = 32 * 32 = 1024` threads. Since now you have more threads than elements, you'll probably need to check this via some condition in your kernel: `if(idx < n) add()`.

In your example a 1D grid and a 1D block should do. You probably want many threads per block (eg. 256 or 1024), otherwise you may exceed your device's block limit since `n` is quite large in your example.

`my_addition_kernel <<< ceil((2^23 - 1) / 1024), 1024 >>>(da, db, dc)`

So you'd have 8192 blocks with 1024 threads each.

(Sometimes you just can't fit everything into the device at once. Then you have to go a bit differently about it, eg. do multiple iterations with subdata.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply,  it has helped a lot, can I just ask how you would actually assign threads in those other cases to this problem as it is part of the task unfortunately.

int i = threadIdx.x; is the code I have for thread allocation.
How would this be changed for the other 6 scenarios? Thank you

Comment: I won't go through all of them, but eg. for mutliple 2D block in 1D grid *I think* you could do `<<< 8192, dim3(32, 32) >>>` and for multiple 2D blocks in 2D grid: `<<< dim3(4096, 2), dim3(32, 32) >>>`. You're basically splitting the 1D case up, but the overall #threads stays the same. I'm assuming `numThreadPerBlock = 1024` here. I've never actually called an addition kernel like this though, and I haven't double checked it either.

Comment: `int i = threadIdx.x` will be local per block, and you definitely can't have `2^23` many in one block. To get the global index you do `int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x`.